# Terraform Instance enumeration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to enroll enumerated VM instances to Azure Backup Service. However, I am getting an error:

```
* azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm.consul_and_vault: source_vm_id must be a single value, not a list
```

Here is the snippet of my code where I create VM instances in Azure:

```
###############################################################################
# Deploy VMs and Configure Consul and Vault Services
###############################################################################

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "consul" {
  name                             = "consul${count.index + 1}"
  #name                             = "${var.consul_cluster_prefix}-consul-${count.index + 1}"
  location                         = "${var.deployment_location}"
  resource_group_name              = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  availability_set_id              = "${azurerm_availability_set.consul.id}"
  network_interface_ids            = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.consul_nic.*.id, count.index + 1)}"]
  vm_size                          = "${var.consul_vm_size}"
  delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true
  count                            = "${var.consul_instance_count}"
  tags {
    ownerinfo            = "${var.ownerinfo}"
    costcenter           = "${var.costcenter}"
    deploymenttype       = "${var.deploymenttype}"
    notificationdistlist = "${var.notificationdistlist}"
    env_info             = "${var.environmentinfo}"
    application_name     = "${var.applicationname}"
    platform             = "${var.platform}"
  }
  storage_image_reference {
    id  ="${var.consul_image_id}"
 }
...
```

Later on, when creating a backup set, I am attempting to reference enumerated VM instances:

```
##########################################################################################
# AzureRM Virtual Machine Into Azure Recovery Services Vault
##########################################################################################

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "backup2vault" {
    name    = "azurerecoveryvaulti1"
    location = "${var.deployment_location}"
    resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
    sku     = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm" "consul_daily" {
  name                = "azurerecoveryvaultpolicy1"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup2vault.name}"

  backup = {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }

  retention_daily = {
    count = 1
  }
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm" "consul_and_vault" {
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup2vault.name}"
  source_vm_id        = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.consul.*.id}"
  backup_policy_id    = "${azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm.consul_daily.id}"
}
```

Problem seems to be with how variable `source_vm_id` is referencing enumerated instances:

```
source_vm_id        = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.consul.*.id}"
```

...which is resulting in error:

```
 azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm.consul_and_vault: source_vm_id must be a single value, not a list
```

Question is, how can I reference enumerated instances in my case?

Tremendously appreciate any feedback.

A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enumerate the `azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm.consul_and_vault` resource to the same length as the `azurerm_virtual_machine.consul` resource. Then, you can reference each `azurerm_virtual_machine.consul.id` as an element in the `count.index` at the same element number as `azurerm_virtual_machine.consul`. It would then look like:

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm" "consul_and_vault" {
  count               = "${var.consul_instance_count}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup2vault.name}"
  source_vm_id        = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.consul.*.id[count.index]}"
  backup_policy_id    = "${azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm.consul_daily.id}"
}
```

Note also that the `azurerm_virtual_machine.consul.*.id` syntax is outputting the `id` as a list.

Comment: Thanks Matt, you're awesome!!